# Z3 hanging for universal quantification

Tags: z3

I am new to z3 and am trying to use z3 for the following problem:

[image: formula]

My z3 code is the following:

```
(declare-sort A)
(declare-sort O)
(declare-const o1 O)
(declare-const o2 O)

(declare-fun x () A)
(declare-fun g (A O) A)
(declare-fun f (A) Int)

(assert (= (f x) 0))
(assert (forall ((a A))
        (forall ((o O))
            (= (f (g a o)) (+ (f a) 1))
        )
    )
)

(assert (= (f (g x o1)) 1))
(assert (= (f (g (g x o2) o1)) 2))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

When I run this (using z3 with no flags), it seems to hang (I allowed it to run for an hour before stopping it). I know that z3 is not a decision procedure for universally quantified formulae in general. Is this problem beyond z3 or is there something else I need to do to get z3 to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely beyond the capabilities of typical SMT solving and z3 indeed. You can experiment with patterns as described here: https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h28 However, I've tried a few most obvious parents but it didn't help. Even if you found the right "pattern," these tend to be rather fragile. So, yes; I'd say this is beyond what a typical SMT solver can handle.